# Configuration of PostgreSQL error messages

Tags: postgresql, configuration, unixodbc

I have a question concerning the error messages in PostgreSQL.
I noticed that in case of some failure PostgreSQL make a report in the form of text message but it does not contain error code id.
For instance:

```
ERROR: Relation "mytable" already exists or
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "id"
```

Could you please suggest a way to make PostgreSQL ***including native error code id*** to  messages  for instance as follows:

```
42P07  ERROR: Relation "mytable" already exists or
23505  ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "id"
```

.

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to have followed up at https://stackoverflow.com/q/45353684/398670

Answer (score 2):

You can change the parameter `log_error_verbosity` in `postgresql.conf` file to change the amount of information being logged during errors. By default, its value is default. You can change it to verbose to include more information about the errors.

Comment: Thank You for quick response.
I changed **log_error_verbosity** param and saw that the format of log entries in pg_log directory has been changed. Now these messages contain PG error code ID.

But when I run some wrong command in psql or try to get error message via **ODBC driver** _SQLGetDiagRec()_ call I am still getting the error message without native Postgresql error ID. 
Could you please suggest anything else ?

Comment: To get error codes in psql use `\set VERBOSITY verbose` in the psql prompt first. Then try running some wrong commands.